# How to run Zombienet with native built binaries?

Tags: zombienet

how to run Zombienet tests with natively built parachain and polkadot validator?
It seems in the Zombienet's Readme it is not very clear on how to set that up...

Can I use the same test file(.feature file) ?

My current network file:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:{{POLKADOT_VERSION}}"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "{{COLLATOR_URL}}"
  command = "parachain-collator"
  args = ["-lparachain=debug"]
  
[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

How can I change the relayer and parachain images to local native binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for Zombienet team's quick reply!

For my fixed network file above:

`default_command = "polkadot"` => Rename your built polkadot validator binary to "polkadot"

`command = "parachain-collator"` => Rename your built parachain collator binary to "parachain-collator"

Then add the binaries above into your bash PATH:

```
export PATH="/path/to/built/binary_folder/:$PATH"
```

Check if your binaries can be accessed in PATH:

```
polkadot --version
parachain-collator --version
```

Then run my Zombienet feature file with native provider:

```
zombienet-linux1256 -p native test zombienet_tests/05-small-network.feature
```